# How can one temporarily disable Left-mouse-button activated code in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want code to be triggered by the left-mouse-button *only* if the variable `toggle` is equal to 1, and otherwise I want the left-mouse-button to work normally.

I tried the following:

```
LButton::
if (toggle=1) {
  ;do code
}
```

The problem with the code above is that if the variable `toggle` is equal to 0 then the left-mouse-button will simply not work.

Even if I change the code to

```
LButton::
if (toggle=1) {
  ;do code
}
else {
Click
}
```

then the mouse button will click (albeit a simulated one) but functionality such as dragging will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked out [#If](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm)? Thy this:

```
#If ( toggle = 1 )
LButton::
   ;do code
Return
#If
```